# External user in SharePoint community site

Tags: site-collection, 2013, extranet, community

I use SharePoint 2013.

I have a community site in my site collection.
I want to give a external user acces to that site. 
I don't want to give him the right to see every topic.

How can assign him a category, so he only has acces on that?

or is there a alternative?

please provide me the steps?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your site structure?  The terms 'topic' and 'category' are typically used in metadata and would not be securable in and of themselves.

Comment: Well user logs on to the main page and then there is a link to the community site. but it is also possible to go directly to the community site. When they are logged in they see the standard community site features. i created a few keyword. which they can discus on. nothing much.